why ‘& {}’ can exclude null and undefined in TypeScript？
Today, when I was looking at the ts definition file, I found that '&{}' is used here, but I can't understand why ‘& {}’ can exclude null and undefined in TypeScript.In Javascript '&' mean is bitwise and

And I didn't look up the relevant information. Can you help me explain or  tell me where I can look it up？

"In Javascript '&' mean is bitwise" — TypeScript types aren't JavaScript, so & isn't bitwise in that context.

& is the intersection type. An intersection of two types A and B like type T = A & B means that T should have all props from A and B.
If you check this playground:
type X = null & {};

X is never.
Because type X now wants to be a type which is assignable of both null and empty object type, but Empty Object Type is used to represent any value except null and undefined. Every other type string,number and of course object is assignable to {}, as primitive types also have their own properties.
And that is how NonNullable also works, by creating an intersection of the two.

okey,thank you very much,i can understant & in ts,thank you thank you
